# Bootstrapping epics

Tags: redux-observable

I was wondering if there was a best practice for triggering epics when the application loads? I can think of a few methods:

- Dispatch a generic init action.

  - Payload can only have generic data, so not much good if your epic relies of getting is data via the action.
  - Single dispatch and run of reducers/epics.
  - Semantic and therefore easy to understand.
- Dispatch a specific action for each epic.

  - Doesn't require a change to the epics
  - Creates a lot of unnecessary dispatch calls, as actions are dispatched with state already in the store.
- Use startsWith operator.

  - Great for epics that are started and never changed.
  - Can create the relevant action with data from store.getState() but this is a bit tedious to do inline.

These different methods have their pros and cons, but I was interesting to see if I had missed something obvious or built in.

It would be good to cover this in the documentation recipes?

Comment: @jayphelps is this something you could comment on?